# How to change direction of text in QPlainText to RightToLeft?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to change direction of text in QPlainText from LTR to RTL, so, how can i do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation mentions, you can no longer use the QWidget setLayoutDirection call in Qt 4.7. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#layoutDirection-prop

It appears that newer versions only allow this to be controlled from the QApplication setLayoutDirection. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#layoutDirection-prop